# elasticsearch using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read huge volume of data like around 1 TB and load into elastic search .

1. what are the possible ways I can check for loading that much volume
2. here I am browing coding options for the same and thought of using python multi processing .

   so i split my large file into small chunks then used this sample to read my files and to load into elasticsearch using the multi processeing . Is this right kind of approach?

python code:

```
def read_sample(filename):
    my code to read from file and output s the element


def elasticinsert(filename):
    deque(helpers.parallel_bulk(es,read_sample(filename),index="sample",doc_type="samples"), maxlen=0)

def main():
    data=[]
    data=[filename for filename in list_of_sample_files]

    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2,maxtasksperchild=1)
    result=pool.map(elasticinsert,data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now I am getting some kind of SSL issues and here is the traceback . How can I resolve this ??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 76, in perform_request
    response = self.session.send(prepared_request, **send_kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)    
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)

requests.exceptions.SSLError:  [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:1769)
```

Any help for me . Thanks for all your time .

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution here would be to use a threading interface instead of multiprocessing.

```
import threading
import queue

def read_sample(filename):
   '''my code to read from file and output s the element'''


def elasticinsert(filename):
      ''' Some Operaitions '''
      q.put(filename)#Can be any data you want to put


def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    threads=[]

    for i in list_of_sample_files:
        t = threading.Thread(target=elasticinsert, args=(i,))
        threads.append(t)
        t[-1].start()

    [t.join() for t in threads]
    while not q.empty():
        q.get()
```